# Resetting a server

Tags: linux

I have an assignment to create a server from an empty domain. I plan to follow certain guide in the internet about how to. My question is: Assuming that I screwed up the tutorial, what's the command to reset the server back to it's empty state before installing like postfix or dovecot?

Comment: snapshots: https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: err could you elaborate?

Comment: Virtual environments offer a feature called snapshots.  They allow you to revert an *entire* (virtual) machine back to a previous state.  Configure a virtual machine as you want.  Take a snapshot.  Then play around.  Then revert the snapshot to start over.

Comment: so, i logged in to the server using ssh, use snapshot, install postfix and such, then if i did a mistake, revert the snapshot?

Comment: yes.  sort of.  The snapshot and revert are done 'outside' of the machine.  but you understand the concept.  This is not small topic, I suggest you do some reading.  There are lots of similar solutions depending on your particulars, virtualbox is one of many, but is a pretty good one.

Comment: Hmm so, the conclusion is, i should snapshot before i install postfix, then i logged to the domain given to me by my teacher, install postfix and such. IF i want to revert back the domain to it's clean state, i just need to use the snapshot then?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: umm, i'm confused as to is snapshot could reset the changes i made to the domain i was given?

Answer (score 2):

For virtual machines like VMWare / VirtualBox, you can create a snapshot as Stephen suggested,

But in case you're not running a virtual machine, you can use docker, [start reading from here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/)

P.S If you're worried about software installation and configurations, simply remove the software and restore the config files should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog entry on how to do something along those lines with Ansible and a short Perl script a while back:

https://grep.be/blog/en/computer/Resetting_a_Raspberry_Pi_to_default_using_Ansible

Don't worry about the 'raspberry pi' bit in the URL -- the described method works for any system, really.

The idea of that method is that you use a whitelist to describe for yourself what an 'empty' system looks like in the Perl script, and then you have it output Ansible facts for the superfluous things it finds on the system. You can then use Ansible to remove those things. The version on my blog only cares about packages, but that method could equally well be expanded to look at files, users, or various other things.